# Insert data from view automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have tables that contain current stock of different types of products, their location and cost.

I am planning to create a view which will combine this data by the end of every day in order to keep history of my stocks per daily basis as follows:

```
opening stock (of yesterday) ---  Sales ---- Closing Stock (today)
```

But I don't know what is the best way to implement this and to avoid data duplication. I'm using SQL Server, but I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: What do you mean by *avoid duplication*?  Views do not add data to your database and if you are trying to return the stock that is present at three different points in time, you should be *wanting* duplication if the same item was present at all three...

Comment: I mean when I get data from table into view it will look like transaction history specially for sales so when i get this data from the view into my new table in which I will maintain the history of stocks I don't want it to take all records every time. I hope it is clear?!

Comment: Then use the `where` clause...?  I would personally recommend you have a think about your database design here, it sounds very poor and in violation of standard normalisation principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can illustrate with the following steps, i assume your table is defined with primary keys to eliminate duplicate record update.

```
CREATE TABLE TransactionHistory(
                ProductNo varchar(10) not null 
                ,Product_name varchar(100) not null
                ,TransactionDate Date
                ,SalesValue float
 CONSTRAINT [Pk_product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    productno asc
    ,product_name asc
    ,transactionDate asc
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

-- Create a View now  to insert data into the table

```
Create View Vw_TransactionHistory 
as

select 
       ProductNo
      ,Product_name
      ,TransactionDate
      ,SalesValue

 from salesTable

 where transactiondate = getdate ()-15


GO
```

so, view looks at last 15 days data or you could change it to getdate() or getdate()-1

--3rd step Now, create a merge procedure which updates records or inserts new records

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_transactionHistory
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE dbo.TransactionsHistory AS TARGET
    USING Vw_TransactionHistory AS SOURCE
        ON (
                TARGET.ProductNo = SOURCE.ProductNo
                AND TARGET.Product_name = source.Product_name
                AND TARGET.TransactionDate = SOURCE.TransactionDate
                AND TARGET.SalesValue = SOURCE.SalesValue
                )
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET TARGET.ProductNo = SOURCE.ProductNo
                ,TARGET.Product_name = source.Product_name
                ,TARGET.TransactionDate = SOURCE.TransactionDate
                ,TARGET.SalesValue = SOURCE.SalesValue
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (
                ProductNo
                ,Product_name
                ,TransactionDate
                ,SalesValue
                )
            VALUES (
                SOURCE.ProductNo
                ,SOURCE.Product_name
                ,SOURCE.TransactionDate
                ,SOURCE.SalesValue
                );
END
GO
```